# Task.async in Elixir Stream

Tags: parallel-processing, elixir

I want to do a parallel map over a big list. The code looks somewhat like this:

```
big_list
|> Stream.map(&Task.async(Module, :do_something, [&1]))
|> Stream.map(&Task.await(&1))
|> Enum.filter filter_fun
```

But I was checking Stream implementation and as far as I understand `Stream.map` combines the functions and applies combined function to elements in the stream, which would mean that the sequence is like this:

1. Take first element
2. Create async task
3. Wait for it to finish
4. Take second elelemnt...

In that case, it doesn't do it in parallel. Am I right or am I missing something?

If I am right, what about this code?

```
Stream.map Task.async ...
|> Enum.map Task.await ...
```

Is that going to run in parallel?

Comment: read this - http://www.theerlangelist.com/2015/07/beyond-taskasync.html

Comment: @LeninRajRajasekaran broken link

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The second one also doesn't do what you want. You can see it clearly with this code:

```
defmodule Test do
  def test do
    [1,2,3]
    |> Stream.map(&Task.async(Test, :job, [&1]))
    |> Enum.map(&Task.await(&1))
  end

  def job(number) do
    :timer.sleep 1000
    IO.inspect(number)
  end
end

Test.test
```

You'll see a number, then a 1 second wait, another number, and so on. The key here is that you want to create the tasks as soon as possible, so you shouldn't use the 
lazy `Stream.map` at all. Instead use the eager `Enum.map` at that point:

```
|> Enum.map(&Task.async(Test, :job, [&1]))
|> Enum.map(&Task.await(&1))
```

On the other hand you can use `Stream.map` when awaiting, as long as you do some eager operation later, like your `filter`. That way the awaits will be interspersed with any processing you might be doing on the results.

Answer (score 11):

Elixir 1.4 provides the new [Task.async_stream/5](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Task.html#async_stream/5) function that will return a stream that runs a given function concurrently on each item in an enumerable.

There are also options to specify the maximum number of workers and a timeout, using the `:max_concurrency` and `:timeout` options parameters.

Please note that you don't have to await this Task, because the function returns a stream, so you can either use [Enum.to_list/1](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Enum.html#to_list/1) or use [Stream.run/1](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Stream.html#run/1).

---

This will make your example run concurrently:

```
big_list
|> Task.async_stream(Module, :do_something, [])
|> Enum.filter(filter_fun)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try [Parallel Stream](https://github.com/beatrichartz/parallel_stream).

```
stream = 1..10 |> ParallelStream.map(fn i -> i * 2 end)
stream |> Enum.into([])
[2,4,6,8,10,12,14,16,18,20]
```

UPD 
Or better use [Flow](https://hexdocs.pm/flow/Flow.html)